# Change of coordinates in vector fields on Heisenberg group

Tags: proof-explanation, vector-fields, heisenberg-group

In the book [Geometric Analysis on the Heisenberg Group and Its Generalizations](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Geometric_Analysis_on_the_Heisenberg_Gro.html?id=JceFAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) proposition 1.3 says: Under the change of coordinates
$$ y_1 = x_1 , \, y_2 = x_2, \, \tau = 4t -2x_1x_2,$$
the vector fields
$$ X = \partial_{x_1}, \, Y = \partial_{x_2} +x_1 \partial_t, \,  T = \partial_t $$
are transformed into
$$ X = \partial_{y_1} - 2y_2\partial_{\tau}, \, Y = \partial_{y_2} +2y_1 \partial_{\tau} , \,  T = 4\partial_{\tau}. $$
The author says that the proof follows from the following relationships
$$ \partial_t =   4\partial_{\tau} , \,  \partial_{x_2} = \partial_{y_2} -2y_1 \partial_{\tau} , \, \partial_{x_1} = \partial_{y_1} - 2y_2\partial_{\tau} . $$

I don't understand how this change of coordinates is done, nor how these relations in the demonstration were obtained, can anyone help me understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the chain rule, because the two sets of coordinates are functions of each other. For instance, the derivative with respect to $t = t(y_1,y_2,\tau)$ is given by
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} 
   = \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1} 
    + \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_2} 
    + \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}
   = 0\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1} 
    + 0\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y_2} 
    + 4\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau},
$$
hence $\partial_t = 4\partial_\tau$. In order to speed up those computations, you can carry them out simultaneously with the help of the following relation :
$$
\nabla_{(x_1,x_2,t)} = \frac{\partial(y_1,y_2,\tau)}{\partial(x_1,x_2,t)} \cdot \nabla_{(y_1,y_2,\tau)},
$$
which is nothing else than multidimensional chain rule, where $\nabla_{(x_1,x_2,t)} = (\partial_{x_1},\partial_{x_2},\partial_t)^T$ and $\nabla_{(y_1,y_2,\tau)} = (\partial_{y_1},\partial_{y_2},\partial_\tau)^T$ are the respective gradients and
$$
\frac{\partial(y_1,y_2,\tau)}{\partial(x_1,x_2,t)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & -2x_2 \\
   0 & 1 & -2x_1 \\
   0 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & -2y_2 \\
   0 & 1 & -2y_1 \\
   0 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is the Jacobian matrix of the considered coordinate transformation, so that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \partial_{x_1} \\ \partial_{x_2} \\ \partial_t \end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & -2y_2 \\
   0 & 1 & -2y_1 \\
   0 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \partial_{y_1} \\ \partial_{y_2} \\ \partial_\tau \end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix} \partial_{y_1} - 2y_2\partial\tau \\ \partial_{y_2} - 2y_1\partial_\tau \\ 4\partial_\tau \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now you can substitute the new coordinates in the vector fields; for example, the second vector field becomes :
$$
Y = \partial_{x_2} + x_1\partial_t
  = \left(\partial_{y_2} - 2y_1\partial_\tau\right) + y_1 \cdot 4\partial_\tau 
  = \partial_{y_2} + 2y_1\partial_\tau
$$